# Blackberry Development with AppWorld

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

Where can i find information about Blackberry development with the help of AppWorld?
(most interested to work with subscriptions)
What are the main differences from the development of under the Iphone?

Comment: just check http://developer.blackberry.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Website for blackberry developer](https://developer.blackberry.com/)

[Blackberry Support forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Developer-Support-Forums/ct-p/blackberrydev)